# How to compare GEE models with Linear models in R

Tags: r, anova, model, generalized-estimating-equations, lm

I got a dataset, and I fit the data by linear model first and get a fitted model. and then I introduced a random effect, the subject or id in R arguments. and get a fitted gee model, so how to compare these two models? If I use linear mixed model such as the function lme in R, may I use anova to compare the lmm model and lm model. The difference between the two models is just the random effect. I used the anova function in R and get the answer, I was wondering is it reliable?

```
m1<-lme(A ~ B ,data=data)
m2<-lme(A ~ B ,data=data,random=~1|Name)
```

Comment: What do you mean by reliable?

Comment: I would like to know can I trust the Anova output. I remember Anova is to compare the nested model, so are these two models nested?